# Second monitor 'heads up' display

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors

I'm running Windows 7, and looking for a customizable app that I can run on a second monitor with things like clocks, weather, stock prices, RSS feeds, etc. I'm open to the idea of separate widgets.

Comment: Why not just use Win 7 gadgets??

Comment: @Software Monkey: lol.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use Windows 7 gadgets?

Answer (score 0):

Rainmeter is another option

http://rainmeter.net/RainCMS/?q=Rainmeter101